# Using a div as a border

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a new portfolio site. I am using wordpress and coding in a custom html block.

I want to use a `<div class="hovertrigger" id="hovertrigger1"></div>` as border for another `<div class="wp-block-gmedia-gallery gmedia-shortcode" id="gallery1">[gmedia id=13]</div>`.

In other words, "#gmedia-gallery should be always below .hovertrigger, ideally with a little space.

If I change the html hierarchie my layered divs gets broken. Right now I am using a minus margin with a fixed pixel distance. I want it to be correctly responsive to screen size.

my site: http://lilphil.de/ my current code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  blend-mode: lighten;
  z-index: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 6 / 5;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 400;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.hovertrigger {
  z-index: 1000;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: none;
}

.logoanim {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 6 / 5;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 500;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#gallery1 {
  margin-top: -590px;
}

#hovertrigger1:hover~.logoanim {
  opacity: 1;
}

#hovertrigger1:hover~div.logo {
  opacity: 0
}

.wp-image-536 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wp-image-587 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hovertrigger" id="hovertrigger1"></div>
  <div class="logoanim" id="logoanim1"><img src="http://lilphil.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Comp-1.gif" alt="" class="wp-image-536"></div>
  <div class="logo" id="logo1"><img src="http://lilphil.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Comp1_00000.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-587"></div>
</div>
<div class="wp-block-gmedia-gallery gmedia-shortcode" id="gallery1">[gmedia id=13]</div>
```

I really hope I could explain my problem.

Comment: Hi! I would like to make sure I understand the problem. Do you mean that, when your website layout changes to accommodate screen size (ex. when the layout compresses to fit smaller screens), #gallery1 is no longer beneath #hovertrigger1?

Comment: Exactly. The gallery gets over the hovertrigger (and covers the divs with my logo and gif in it).

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried some things and I think the easiest way is to change

```
#gallery1 {
  margin-top: -590px;
}
```

to

```
#gallery1 {
  margin-top: -38%;
}
```

as the other divs already scale on percentages.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried it already, you may find it useful to use a [grid view](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) layout when designing your web page. Basically, if you divide the entire page into a grid with columns and rows (sized using relative units, like percentages), you can place #gallery1 in the row beneath #hovertrigger1. That way, your divs will always be layered regardless of screen size.

Also, if possible, I recommend using [relative units](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp) instead of pixels so that your webpage elements stay proportioned across different screen dimensions and pixel resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

It needs another div in the HTML Code, so it does look like this:

```
<div>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="hovertrigger" id="hovertrigger1"></div>
    <div class="logoanim" id="logoanim1"><img src="http://lilphil.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Comp-1.gif" alt="" class="wp-image-536"></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo1"><img src="http://lilphil.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Comp1_00000.jpg" alt="" class="wp-image-587"></div>
  
    
</div>

<div class="wp-block-gmedia-gallery gmedia-shortcode" id="gallery1">[gmedia id=13]</div>
```